# returning short int different basic type vc++ error

Tags: c, return-value, return-type

I have a `main.c` which call a function `downsample` which is defined in `downMain.c`

The prototype of `downsample` is

```
short int downsample(short int input);
```

In `downMain.h` i have this function prototype and  `downMain.c` contains definition of the function.

I got below error when compiling

```
E:\demo\main.c(9) : error C2371: 'downsample' : redefinition; different basic types
```

Is it posible to return `short int` ? Why am i getting this error, solution please?!

EDit:

---

I include downMain.h in main.c

Content of downMain.c

```
int call_downsample(int key) {
  if(key == 1)
    downsample(data);
  return 0;
}
```

`downsample` function contains simple skip-copy for loop

content of downMain.h

```
int call_downsample(int key);
short int downsample(short int data);
```

Comment: `Is it posible to return short int ? `: Yes, of course. `Why am i getting this error, solution please?!`: Don't know why o__O

Comment: Can you show your declaration and definition..

Comment: No reason why this doesn't work.  What is on line 9?  Is the function definition the same as the prototype?

Comment: There can be two reasons, 1. He has included downMain.c in main.c. 2. Declaration and definition signature will be different.

Comment: @pranitkothari Added definitions of relevant file

Comment: Please refer to this link ,it shows the same error type and the answer is accepted , it might be helpful                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424239/error-c2371-eb-redefinition-different-basic-types-why-c

Comment: @nmxprime Where is definition of downsample function?

Comment: @pranitkothari in downMain.c

Comment: @hariprasad Thanks that seems working after prototyping in downMain.c . But Why prototyping in downMain.h and including it in main.c doesn't work

Comment: @nmxprime I can only see `call_downsample` definition there.

Comment: @pranitkothari downsample function contains simple skip-copy for loop

Comment: @nmxprime So, whats the problem in showing it.

Comment: Meh.. short and correct example of error would be great. From what i'm able to understand, missing prototype in `downMain.c` cannot affect compilation of `main.c` because they're different translation unit. But anyway, you had implicit declaration somewhere - can't say where without seeing actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function **downsample(data)** is called with in the function **call_downsample(int key)**  , so one thing to do is you have to define the function *downsample(data)* before it is called ,ie; above the function call_downsample(int key).

Refer to this link ,it describes the same problem   [Error C2371: redefinition; different basic types - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424239/error-c2371-eb-redefinition-different-basic-types-why-c)

Comment: To clarify - it just have to be _declared_ at this point, not necessarily implemented.

Comment: Accepting your answer, and +1 for pointing me to exact solution in another post by your comments